# how detect element Drag without jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm try to write very compressed and optimized js for my project , I use jQuery for my project , now I want detect drag an element for do more actions by this drag.

I search many websites and question in here but every place result = use jquery UI.

I can't use jQuery UI , because not optimized in my code and is big for my project.

Now my real question is , how I detect drag item in jQuery alone not with jQuery UI.

my Try code for example :

> $(function() {
>
> ```
> window.isDragging = false;
>
> $('#move').mousedown(function (e){
>     window.mX = e.pageX ;
>     window.mY = e.pageY ;
>     window.isDragging = true;
>
>     $('html').bind('mouseup',function (e){
>         window.isDragging = false;
>         console.log(window.mX+'->'+e.pageX);
>         console.log(window.mY+'->'+e.pageY);
>     });
>
>     $('html').bind('mousemove',function (e){
>         if (window.isDragging){
>             console.log('move ->'+e.pageX+','+e.pageY);
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```
>
> })

almost work good but the mouseup not work always.

Comment: Willing to bet that the overhead of including jQuery UI is less significant than the performance hit you will likely see with a homemade version.

Comment: @AntP But I force try to write the better code the JUI = overhead in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , When mouse up in iframe js mouse up not worked iI was add trigger mouseup in all iframes my problem solved .